# ¿Qué función tiene __declspec(dllexport) y __declspec(dllimport)?

Tags: c++, c

Estoy investigando algunos archivos de `Mesa 3-D graphics library` y me he topado con este código:

**gl.h**

```
//..
#if defined(__WIN32__) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  if (defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__)) && defined(BUILD_GL32) /* tag specify we're building mesa as a DLL */
#    define GLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#  elif (defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__)) && defined(_DLL) /* tag specifying we're building for DLL runtime support */
#    define GLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
//..
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Qué función tiene `__declspec(dllexport)` y  `__declspec(dllimport)` y cuándo deben de usarse?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estos atributos son específicos de Windows y se emplean para construir / enlazar DLLs.

`__declspec(dllexport)` indica al linker de la librería en cuestión que ese elemento (función, clase, etc.) debe ser visible fuera de la DLL. Sin este atributo el método únicamente sería visible dentro de la librería.

`__declspec(dllimport)` viene a complementar la cláusula anterior y permite al linker (esta vez el de la aplicación o librería que enlace con la DLL anterior), realizar las operaciones oportunas para localizar correctamente el punto de entrada de dicha función.

En el caso de Linux, únicamente habría que indicar la exportación de símbolos mediante el atributo `__attribute__(visibility("default"))`. Para la importación de símbolos no hay un atributo especial.

Lo más común suele ser controlar la inclusión de una etiqueta u otra mediante directivas de precompilador, de tal forma que la misma cabecera pueda utilizarse tanto para compilar la librería como para enlazar a sus funciones:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define __DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define __DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#elif _GCC
#define __DLLEXPORT __attribute__(visibility("default"))
#define __DLLIMPORT 
#endif

#ifdef ISDLL
#define DLLEXPORT __DLLEXPORT
#else
#define DLLEXPORT __DLLIMPORT
#endif

DLLEXPORT void mifunc();
```

Con el ejemplo anterior, basta que al compilar la DLL se defina el símbolo ISDLL para que la función se compile con la opción de exportación `__declspec(dllexport)`. En caso contrario se compilará con la opción de importación `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Comment: Puedo entender que declspec se encarga simplemente de envolver cosas especificas de Microsoft saludos

Comment: cierto, para linux creo recordar que había que usar algo tal que... `__attribute__(visibility("default"))`, aunque en este caso únicamente es para `dllexport`. Para `dllimport` no hay un equivalente.